Does a vertical line have no slope, or infinite slope?
I have heard some textbooks that vertical lines have no slope (not a slope of $0$, rather, no slope at all). However, other textbooks say that the slope of a vertical line is $\infty$, where the $\infty$ is neither positive nor negative infinity, but an unsigned infinity. Which is the right answer? Or, perhaps a better question is, which is more useful? The main reason I am asking this rather elementary question, is because I am interested in a formula for the change of slope for a rotated coordinate system. I think, in that context, it is best to have the convention that a vertical line has a slope of unsigned infinity, so that the formulas can still work. After all, a vertical line will be non-vertical in a rotated coordinate system.

If you have already decided what answer you want, for a system only you are apparently using, why ask here what other people do for systems that are not the one you wish to use?

Are you familiar with the projective line and homogeneous coordinates? Each "slope" is a point in this space, including the extra point at infinity: $+\infty = \frac{1}{0} = \frac{-1}{0} = -\infty$.

"Which is the right answer?"  Never ask mathematicians what "right" answers are.

This is one of those questions where any answer cannot be enlightening or interesting, so it gets my downvote.

Because slopes are fundamentally ratios, the best way to understand them in the plane is by encoding them as a tuples $(x,y)$, where $(x,y)$ is some point on the line different from $(0,0)$. From a "classical" representation of a line as $y = ax$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, you can find the slope in our new system as $(1,a)$. Two tuples $(x,y)$ and $(x', y')$ represent the same slope when they lie on the same line, that is, when they are multiples of one another. Your "vertical" line now has slope $(0,1)$, while the horizontal line has slope $(1,0)$.
Technically, this idea is called the projective line. It can be thought of as the real line with a single point at infinity.

Re: "$(x,y)$, where $(x,y)$ is some point on the line different from $(0,0)$": That's not quite right, unless we assume that the line passes through $(0,0)$. I think you need to write something like "$(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$, where $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are distinct points on the line."
